# Arma 3 Epoch-How do I eat or drink?

Tags: arma-3, epoch

Playing the Epoch mod for Arma 3, how do I eat or drink? I have food and drinks in my inventory to eat or drink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in your inventory, double-tap with the Left Mouse Button and select "Drink/Eat".